# Hardware key shows on-screen keyboard on Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I discovered a strange behaviour in Flutter. I have a Zebra PDA with Android, and so I have an hardware keyboard on the device. If I press an hardware key on the device keyboard, the on-screen keyboard shows up, and I don't think that is supposed to happen. After some investigation, I found out that this happen as soon as I show a widget with a `TextField` on it. After the first time the on-screen keyboard appears, every time I press an hardware key the on-screen keyboard appears. This is very frustrating, because if I use hardware keys of course I don't need the on-screen keyboard. I don't really understand if this is an expected behaviour and, if so, how can I avoid it.

Comment: Have you tried running other apps in your "Zebra PDA with android" aside from Flutter apps with `TextField`?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be an issue with Flutter, but rather on the device that you're using. If the device displays the softkeyboard on hardware keyboard key presses, it's likely that you need to have the softkeyboard disabled on the device's Settings.

On stock Android Settings, it's under `System > Languages & input > Physical keyboard`. Then toggle 'Show virtual keyboard'

I've also tried setting `TextField` keyboardType to null to see if it can forcefully disable the softkeyboard, but doing so just shows the default softkeyboard.

```dart
TextField(
  keyboardType: null
),
```